# Horizontal Scroll Bar Issue - On Smaller Screens

Tags: css

I'm working on http://www.lceonline.co.uk

When working on a smaller screen res, anything less than 1000px, I'm getting a horizontal scroll bar appear. This happens on all browsers.

I've tried

```
overflow-x : hidden;
```

but then the web pages' background doesnt repeat, it just seems to be one large gray background. It also is a css-3 property, One i'd rather try and avoid.

I've had a look at the sites' DIV tags and still cant see what is actually causing the problem. I havent built this from scratch, someone else worked on it before me and I feel they have used too many containers.

Can someone provide me with a possible solution on how to get rid of it?

Thanks

Comment: I don't get any scrollbar at all!

Comment: "On Smaller Screens"? or resizing windows to suit..

Comment: nope, still no scroll bars. why would you want to hide them without providing a way to see what I can no longer scroll to. I'm confused as to why that is happening.

Comment: It appears @Jason Gennaro replicated this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that

`#page-container` and `#page-container2` both have `width:1000px;`

If you remove the width from both of those the scrollbar disappears, as does the centring and the gray background.

Comment: I then need the centering to still work with the gray background being there too.

Comment: Did you fix it @StuBlackett?  I checked the page now and there are no horizontal scrollbars.

Comment: I did thanks Jason. The overflow-x: hidden; was applied to #page-container and it appears to have worked. Many Thanks.